# sqlalchemy 2.0 orm bulk upsert one-to-many relationships

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I am trying to bulk insert into multiple tables using sqlalchemy 2.0 ORM using the async engine. The table hierarchy is as follows.

```
table A -> table B -> table C
```

During insertion, I get a batch of JSON objects resembling table A which contain the table B and table C data as well.
Hence I have to construct an orm instance from each json instance for table A and use `session.add()` individually. This slows things down.

If I use the bulk `insert(...).values(...)` api it gets faster but I can only insert into one table, as I couldn't figure out a way to make relationships work using `insert` api.

Is there any way I can make such deeply nested insert more performant?

Comment: Probably just three batches of inserts?  If you don't have the ids already then you have to either pre-generate or use returning to get them back and use them on the next set of relationships.

Comment: So I guess do you already have the pks and fks assigned?

Comment: As @IanWilson suggests, if you have all natural primary keys then you could parse out the JSON and bulk insert to each table separately. If not, then you can get SQLAlchemy to take care of the PK/FK relationships for you or you could "roll your own" solution … if you honestly believe that you could do a better job.